# calling jquery namespace function from within namespace

Tags: jquery

if I have a jquery namespace like so:

```
 var sc = {
          calcResult: function(){
                 //do stuff
                },
           initialise: function () {
              $('#myid').click(function(){
               //would like to call calcResult() here
              }
           }
```

How do I call calcResult from within the initialise function? I tried `this.calcResult()` and `sc.calcResult()` but both complain with undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also call the `sc.initialise()` somewhere to bind the `click` event handler? In the snippet below it works with `sc.calcResult()`

```js
var sc = {
  calcResult: function() {
    //do stuff
    alert("Do stuff");
  },
  initialise: function() {
    $('#myid').click(function() {
      //would like to call calcResult() here
      sc.calcResult();
    });
  }
}

sc.initialise();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myid">Click</button>
```

Comment: I must have had a typo or something because now that I've reinstated the code, it's working. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`sc` object looks like a standalone object (`calcResult` belong to that particular object and not to some specific constructor function prototype). So you need to point to the `sc` object itself so you can use the `calcResult` (function) property. Then, you have two options:

create a reference to the appropriate this object in `initialise` function scope:

```
initialise: function () {
    var that = this;
    $('#myid').click(function(){
        // "that" variable points to the right reference
        // the object that sc points to
        that.calcResult()
    });
}
```

You could also use the `sc` variable directly

```
var sc = {
    calcResult: function(){
    },
    initialise: function () {
        $('#myid').click(function(){
            sc.calcResult()
        });
    }
};
```

But depending on what you try to achieve, you may prefer one solution over the other.

If you have similar object like `sc` having the same functions as direct properties, you should probably create a constructor so that properties functions belong to the constructor prototype instead of copying every function onto every particular "instance" object.